# Error parsing when reversing code

Tags: c++, enterprise-architect

I try to make a class diagram from existing C++ code using Enterprise Architect 9.3.935. I do Code Engineering / Import Source Directory and then select my directory.

However, I get tons of error of type: 
"There was an error parsing C:\xxxxx # on line xxxx. Unexpected symbol: XXXXX. 
You may need to define a language macro."

In the code, I have a macro for exporting DLL and most of my class look like :

class MACRO_FOR_DLL_EXPORT CMyClassName
{
...
}

or

class MACRO_FOR_DLL_EXPORT CMyClassName : public CHerMother
{
...
}

The unexpected symbol is usually "{" in the first case and "CHerMother" in the second.

How to fix this issue, is it related with the macro ?

Comment: any hint on the application you are using to do that?

Comment: Read your post objectively, is there enough information to assist other people, such as the smallest amount of code that creates the issue?

Comment: Sorry, let me know if it is now easier to understand the context

Comment: When you say you "have a macro", do you mean in the source or in EA?

Comment: @Uffe : in my code. I just edited my post to reflect it. Got it fix by defining the symbol as macro in EA but I'd be happy to hear what you have to say about the problem I had.

Comment: @Palmira Thanks for the upvote. You can accept the answer by clicking on the 'check' mark shown at the left side beneath it. This will indicate for others it worked for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare several [Language specific macros](http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/9.3/software_engineering/languagemacros.html) in your EA project, to ignore these when reverse engineering (parsing) code. There's a number of standard C/C++ framework macros predefined natively by EA.